# Outlook VBA Copy part (selection) of mailbody

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to copy the text you have selected in a mailbody to a variable

eg

```
Sub cpytxt()
  Set txt = Selection
  'Do something
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Crédits: gmayor, Source/Fonte: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?52985-VBA-get-selected-text-from-Outlook-email-body-and-use-in-Excel

```
Public Sub ShowTextSelected()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim strText As String

    On Error Resume Next
    'Get Outlook if it's running
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    'Outlook wasn't running, so cancel
    If Err <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is not running so nothing can be selected!"
        GoTo lbl_Exit
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    With OutMail
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        strText = wdDoc.Application.Selection.Range.Text
    End With
    MsgBox strText
lbl_Exit:
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Just what i needed, thank you

Comment: Would it also be possible to grab part of Subject?   I can see olInsp are set to .Getinspector, but not specific to "body" so how to set it to "subject" ?

Comment: This Getinspector, not see selection in the subject, but "OutApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)" is the full subject, this can be usefull.

Comment: Yes, i know. But it is the Getinspector that have the Selection property, so i cant find a way around it.

Comment: I don't found solution, but you can use split, left, right, mid and len, internal functions to select word what you need of subject.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but i get a lot og mail with a reference i subject, somtimes with a lot og other crap, so i dont know exactly where the ref. is. thats why i would likt to select it first. thanks again.